# finding all analytic functions that satisfy some condition

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all analytic functions $f(z)$ which are analytic everywhere in the entire complex plane and which satisfy the condition: $f(2-i)=4i$. I thought about representing f in a power series, i got $f(z)= \frac{(-4-4i)z^n}{1-z}$ but this function is not analytic everywhere, so how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is entire (analytic in the complex plane $\Bbb C$) then
$$ \begin{aligned}
&\quad f(2-i) = 4i \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \quad f(z) - 4i \text{ has a zero at } z =  2-i \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \quad f(z) - 4i = (z - (2-i))g(z) \text{ for some entire function $g$.}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

You can also represent $f$ as a power series at $z_0 = 2-i$:
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-(2-i))^n
$$
Then
$$ \begin{aligned}
&\quad f(2-i) = 4i \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \quad a_0 = 4i \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \quad f(z) = 4i +  (z-(2-i)) \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1} (z-(2-i))^n \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \quad f(z) = 4i + (z - (2-i))g(z) \text{ for some entire function $g$.}
\end{aligned}
$$